# Transform comparison routine to Intel SIMD

Tags: c, x86, intel, sse, simd

I have a routine where is should test if a float number is less than zero or not.  If yes I should store the sign and I get it is absolute values.

```
int sign = 1;
if (x < 0)
{
    sign = -1;
}
x = fabs(x);
```

I looked into Intel SIMD intrinsics and I found this instruction `dst = _mm_cmplt_ps(a,b)` that generate a vector containing (0xffffffff for true) or (0 for false) but I am stuck there; how can I know which element of the `dst` vector is negative or not to build the `sign_vector`.

Comment: What do you do with `sign` after that?  Are you sure you need 2's complement integer `-1` / `+1` instead of `-1` / 0 or something else?  Also, does `x<0` need to be a correct IEEE compare that treats `x = -0.0` or `x = -NaN` as not `<0.0`?  If so you need `_mm_cmplt_ps` instead of Paul R's sign-bit extraction.  But if not, Paul's answer looks like a good way to get exactly what you asked for, but you could maybe simplify it depending on what you do next.

Answer (score 3):

With one small exception (x==+0.0f), you can generate the integer mask using the instruction `sign`:

```
_mm_sign_epi32(_mm_set1_epi32(1), x)
```

This will negate 1, if x<0, but produces the sign==0 when x==0.

If 0 is not allowed, x can be made nonzero by oring with `0<mask<0x80000000`.

```
auto s=_mm_set1_epi32(1);
auto y=_mm_or_si128(x, s); // fix for x==0
s=_mm_sign_epi32(s, y);
```

Comment: `-NaN` is another exception where this behaves differently from the code in the question, assuming `x < 0` is an IEEE compare.  But yes, nice idea if it turns out the OP really does need +1 / -1 and can't just sum compare results and correct for the offset at the end or something.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input values are in a vector `__m128 v`:

```
__m128 vmask = _mm_set1_ps(-0.0f);      // create sign bit mask
__m128 vsign = _mm_and_ps(v, vmask);    // create vector of sign bits (MSB)
__m128i vsigni = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_srai_epi32((__m128i)vsign, 30), _mm_set1_epi32(1));
                                        // convert sign bits to integer +1/-1 (if needed (*))
v = _mm_andnot_ps(vmask, v);            // clear sign bits in v (i.e. v = fabsf(v))
```

(*) rather than wasting cycles generating +1/-1 for the sign, consider whether you could just work with the sign bits directly, and omit this step.

Comment: If the OP can use an integer `0` / `-1` result, an integer `pcmpgtd` against zero could test the sign bit, as an alternative to right shifting.  Or SSE4.1 `blendps` to select between integer +1 / -1 bit patterns, but that has extra bypass latency on Intel CPUs and is 2 uops for port5 on Haswell so can bottleneck the shuffle port.

Comment: You can avoid the `and`:  Use `srai` on the FP bit pattern directly, then set the low bit with `_mm_or_si128` instead of `_mm_add_epi32`.  That leaves the upper 31 bits as copies of the FP sign bit.  (Note that you're assuming that it's ok to treat `-0.0` and `-NaN` as less than `+0.0` in the OP's code, so looking at just the sign bit isn't the same as an FP compare.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, all good points - at the back of my mind I was thinking that the OP might actually be able to just work with the sign bits rather than wasting time generating +1/-1 values, hence the "if needed" in the comment. I should have made a note of this in the question though - I'll do that shortly. If the OP definitely needs +1/-1 for the sign though then I like your idea of srai-ing the float directly.